# Computed function return null - problem with fetch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new in JS (and vue too) and have problem witch fetch data. My target is - want to save all data from API and using them in functions.

Code:

```
<div>{{ dotToComma }} kg</div>
```

Vue:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      weight: null
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.api();
  },

  methods: {

    //this is working correctly
    async api() {
      const api = await fetch("/reporting/patient/values");
      const data = await api.json();
      this.weight = Math.round(data.weight * 10) / 10
    }
  },

  computed: {
    //this.weight is still null
    dotToComma() {
      return this.weight.replace(".", ",");
    }
  }
};
```

Where is the problem? Thank you

UPDATE:

function replace in dotToComma is working only for strings, so you have to add toString() function:

```
return this.weight.toString().replace(".", ",");
```

Comment: Not worked on Vue.. may be try to call dotToComma with () like <div>{{ dotToComma() }} kg</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions won't give you result instantly, so you need to check do you have `this.weight`, or not. Computed will use new value, when it come.
You can read more about JS async realization [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)